# Parent Component in react router which lifecycle method to use?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router, jsx

I Have routes :

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
  <Route path="/" component={Root}>
    <Route path="/shop" component={Shop}>
      <Route path="/items" component={AllItems}></Route>
      <Route path="/collections" component={Collections}></Route>
    </Route>
  </Route>
</Router>
```

My parent component Shop :

```
export default class Shop extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state=({
      user: cookie.load('user'),
    })
    this.httpHandler = axios.create({
      baseURL: 'localhost:3000',
      headers: {
        'Authorization': this.state.user.token
      }
    })
  }

  componentWillUpdate () {
    this.httpHandler('/products/')
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log('sdfsdf')
      this.setState({ data: response.data}) 
    }.bind(this))
  }

  render() {
    var childrenWithProps = React.cloneElement(this.props.children, this.state);

    return (
      <div>
        <ShopNav />
        {childrenWithProps}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Child Component:

```
export default class AllItems extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    console.log(this.props)
   }
  render() {
   return(
                <Child products={this.state.winks} />
      )      
  }
}
```

I am trying to use this api call and then pass data down as props to my child components. But, Im not sure what lifecycle event to use, Ive tried componentWillMount and componentWillUpdate but it ends up not even running the api call. I am able to pass down the prop this.state.user, but just wanted a way to pass data. Should I be approaching this another way?

Comment: what's `this.user`? Do you mean `this.state.user` ?

Comment: oops yeah this.state.user

Comment: `componentWillMount` should work well. I've tested it locally with no problems. What version of React and react-router?

Comment: "react-router": "^2.8.1",
    "react": "^0.14.8",

Comment: I think my problem is when making the call in componentWillMount() I do get a response, but when i try to  setState of the response, I do not get any of the data being passed as props. I think im missing a step where I need to make the call then set the state and have it passed down as prop. Im not too sure though

Comment: First of all there is not such state as data in your state variable. Try and initialise it before setting it . Secondly instead of bind(this)  to the .then function just try var self = this; and then inside .then function use it as self.setState({data: response.data});

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)` ?
Inside it you could check if nextProps object is the same as your state and update your state.

I hope that's what you are looking for